# Re-link installed apps to Play Store

Tags: applications, google-play-store

After installing custom ROM and downloading most of my apps from PC and installing them offline, my Play Store account is peculiar. Some apps I uninstalled weeks ago but I can still see on Play Store desktop, many apps are shown installed on Play Store mobile but not on the desktop, and many unlinked apps.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is **rooted**, then **Titanium Backup** app has a relevant feature that might work:

1. Tap the app you want to link from the list of apps on the titanium backup app
2. switch to the "Special features" tab
3. You will find "attach to market(forced)"

There's also an [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1234898) about this.

Answer (score -1):

I overcame this by clicking the install button on the desktop Play Store on apps one by one.

On my desktop, I go to Google Play then find the un-linked apps one by one and click on the install button. Then on my phone, I can see those apps are included on my apps list in Play Store app.